# Minimizing cross entropy over a restricted domain?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, cross-entropy, importance-sampling, maximum-entropy

Suppose $f(x;q)$ is the true distribution. The support of the random variable $X$ is $\Omega$. Suppose, I am interested in a particular subset of $\Xi \subset \Omega$. I would like to minimize the cross entropy of the two distributions over $\Xi$:

$$\max_{p} \sum_{x \in \Xi} f(x;q) \log f(x;p).$$

I need to show that:

$$\sum_{x \in \Xi} f(x;q) \leq \sum_{x \in \Xi} f(x;p^*),$$

where $f(x;p^*)$ is the optimal reference distribution. I believe the claim is correct and it should hold at least for a range of pdf's, otherwise, importance sampling phenomenon would not have worked. Unfortunately, I can not find any proof of the claim.

Comment: Isn't it easy to show explicitly that the minimizer is proportional to $f(x;q)$?  The result immediately follows.

Comment: @whuber I do not think it is that easy. If yes, could you please help?

Comment: @whuber If you want you could assume some specific distributions.  Also, you can check the answer by statisticsboy321 to my post below: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4728893/maximizing-the-weighted-sum-of-log-likelihood-function?noredirect=1#comment10027982_4728893

Comment: What makes this easy are two things.  (1) The Lagrange multiplier approach is straightforward.  (2) Alternatively, you can exploit the fact that a distribution maximizes its cross-entropy.  Done.

Comment: @whuber I used the lagrange multiplier approach. But it is not really flowing from that. I get the closed form solution for the optimizer (check the link I send in the previous comment please) but it is not easy to prove the claim with it. At least I do not see it. If it is easy for you, please share it with me as I struggle with it .

Comment: Simply replace $f(;q)$ by its truncation to $\Xi.$

Comment: @whuber Could you please write your ideas in mathematical way and I will accept your solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147952/discussion-between-samir-orujov-and-whuber).

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs%27_inequality#Gibbs'_inequality, referenced in the answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/488038/919.

Comment: I solved it, but what you mentioned is not the direct way to proof.

Comment: It's hard to imagine anything more direct than a one-liner!

Comment: @whuber Please write that ine line and surprise me in a mathematical way.

Comment: I already have, several times over.

Comment: @whuber Forgive my ignorance but I do not see any mathematical equation in your replies.

Comment: @whuber The difference of my question with the answer you sent lies in the fact that I am minimizing the cross entropy over a restricted support of the random variable not over the whole sample space. I believe you misunderstood my question.

Comment: I don't think so: restricting the support of a distribution is called *truncation.*  Because all it does is multiply the base distribution by a constant, the optimization program is unaffected.  That's the proof in a nutshell.

Comment: @whuber yeah, I know truncation. But once you truncate the conditional distribution puts zero mass on non-truncated part of the distribution. I have already got the proof. And it is here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4754299/minimizing-cross-entropy-between-reference-and-target-distributions-over-a-restr